# Using ASP.NET MVC SubControllers with action parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, invoke, subcontroller

I am experimenting with [MvcContrib subcontrollers](http://mhinze.com/subcontrollers-in-aspnet-mvc/). Looking at the example in the source, your parent controller (HomeController) takes an action which takes the subcontroller (FirstLevelSubController) as a parameter:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(FirstLevelSubController firstLevel)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        return View();
    }
}
```

In Home's index view, you call ViewData.Get like this to render the subcontroller and it's view:

```
<div style="border:dotted 1px blue">
    <%=ViewData["text"] %>
    <% ViewData.Get<Action>("firstLevel").Invoke(); %>
</div>
```

The subcontroller's action gets called (ignore the secondlevelcontroller, the example is just demonstrating how you can nest multiple subcontrollers):

```
public class FirstLevelSubController : SubController
{
    public ViewResult FirstLevel(SecondLevelSubController secondLevel)
    {
        ViewData["text"] = "I am a first level controller";
        return View();
    }
}
```

This all works, the subcontroller's view gets rendered inside the parent view.

But what if I need **other parameters** in my home controller's action? For example, I may want to pass a Guid to my controller's index method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(Guid someId, FirstLevelSubController firstLevel)
    {
        //Do something with someId
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        return View();
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to do <% ViewData.Get("firstLevel").Invoke(); %> with parameters. So I can't figure out how to link to my controller from another controller passing a parameter like this:

```
Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(x => x.Index(someThing.Id), "Edit")
```

Perhaps I am approaching this the wrong way? How else can I get my parent controller to use a subcontroller, but also do interesting stuff like accept parameters / arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post:

**Passing objects to SubControllers**
[http://mhinze.com/passing-objects-to-subcontrollers/](http://web.archive.org/web/20100529051721/http://mhinze.com/passing-objects-to-subcontrollers)

Note that SubControllers are deprecated.  They have been replaced with `RenderAction`.

Comment: Good spot - it looks like SubControllers are indeed deprecated - I tried RenderAction, and it just works beautifully first time :) Thanks, I would have spent days trying to get that to work!

Comment: @AbhishekMehta: [This Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100529051721/http://mhinze.com/passing-objects-to-subcontrollers) should suffice for now.  Also note the last paragraph in my answer.